# using insert and select returns null in the table

Tags: mysql, function, sum

I want to select data,subtract it from the sum of a data and insert it into a different table in one query but it always return null in the table.To make it clear,below is my query

```
insert 
    into bill(Amount_paid,BAP) 
select 
    '10',Info.BBP - COALESCE(SUM(bill.Amount_paid),0) 
from 
    Info,bill 
where 
    info.id='1';
```

### | ID | BBP |

|  1 |  20 |

### | BID | AMOUNT_PAID |    BAP |

|   1 |          10 | (null) |

Please how can i deal with such a situation,I have tried my best making this work but to no avail,any idea on how to fix this will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please set up an sqlfiddle.com or give your table definitions so its easy to test possible solutions

Comment: please i have defined my table,any suggestion to make this work.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I imagine your schema to be from the layout above,  this solution is not going to work. What happens when there is a second payment for bill.id 1? or when payments start coming in for bill id 2?

Try this..

```
INSERT INTO bill
SELECT i.id,
       10,
       i.BBP -
  (SELECT COALESCE(sum(b.AMOUNT_PAID),0)
   FROM bill b
   WHERE bid = i.id)
FROM info i
WHERE i.id = 1;
```

Whilst I don't fully understand your system, I see no need for the BAP column as you can always SUM(AMOUNT_PAID) to find out how much has been paid and therefore the balance.

Comment: how do i then calculate for the immediate balance with this situation at hand

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? The balance still outstanding at the time of insert or something else?

Comment: yes please, i want the balance still outstanding at the time of insert and also i want to update the BBP(thus the balance before payment) after inserting into the Amount_Paid.Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Also see this link:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Specification say

```
 The target table of the INSERT statement may appear in the FROM clause of the SELECT 
part of the query. (This was not possible in some older versions of MySQL.) However, 
you cannot insert into a table and select from the same table in a subquery.


When selecting from and inserting into a table at the same time, MySQL creates a 
temporary table to hold the rows from the SELECT and then inserts those rows into the 
target table. However, it remains true that you cannot use INSERT INTO t ... SELECT ...
FROM t when t is a TEMPORARY table, because TEMPORARY tables cannot be referred to 
twice in the same statement (see Section C.5.7.2, “TEMPORARY Table Problems”).
```

So as per this. You are selecting from table bill in inner query, and trying to insert the same value in same table. That is not allowed for some older version of mysql

Comment: this query returns the correct answer,but i want to insert it at the same time,and any time i insert it gives me null value,any idea to solve this problem or if there is a better way out.thanks for your time

Comment: Sure there is a space between bill and (Amount... )

Comment: I meant to say INSERT INTO TABLENAME (COL1, COL2)

For this 'TABLENAME'  and '(' must be seperated by a 'space'

Comment: Please is there any possible solution to my problem. i would be grateful if you would love to help me.thanks

Comment: please i am waiting for your response